non injective holomorphic map having only one zero
I am trying to find a non-injective holomorphic map from $B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ continuous on boundary sending boundary to boundary and it has only one zero (counting multiplicity).
I am trying to disprove it's existence. I have one claim in my mind:
If $f:D\to D$ non-constant, holomorphic and continuous on boundary with $f(\partial D)\subset \partial D$ then for any $c\in D$, $|\{f^{-1}\{c\}|= \text{ number of zeroes counted with multiplicity in }D.$
Sharing any thoughts will be helpful for me.

one zero with multiplicity one. I meant counted with multiplicity

$|{f^{-1}{c}:c\in D}|$ does not make sense. Do you mean $|\cup_{c \in D}f^{-1}{c}|$?

actually I meant $|f^{-1}{c}|=\text{ number of zero counted with multiplicity of f}$, for every $c\in D$

this is basically an immediate consequence of the Argument Principle, though you have to factor the argument through dog-on-leash lemma since  $f$ isn't know to be analytic on the boundary

I think there is no such function:
Let $f \in A(D)$ (i.e. holomorphic on $D:=B(0,1)$ and continuous on $\overline{D}$) with $|f(z)|=1$ $(z \in \partial D)$ and $|f^{-1}(\{0\})| \ge 1$.
Then $f$ can have only finitely many zeros $a_1,\dots,a_n\in D$, say (repeated according to multiplicity).
Consider the finite Blaschke-product
$$
B(z) := \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{z − a_j}{1 − \overline{a_j} z}.
$$
Then $f/B$ and $B/f$ are each holomorphic in $D$, continuous on $\overline{D}$ and $|f(z)/B(z)|=|B(z)/f(z)|=1$ $(z \in \partial D)$.
Apply the Maximum-Modulus Principle to each
to conclude that $|f/B| \le 1$ and $|B/f| \le 1$ on $\overline{D}$. Hence $f/B$ is a unimodular constant: $f=cB$ for some $c \in\partial  D$.
Now $B$ is a $n$-to-$1$ map of $D$ to $D$, hence if $f$ is not injective then $n \ge 2$.

If $f(z_0)=0$, we may consider the function $g(z) = f(\frac{z+z_0}{\overline{z_0}z+1})$, where $z\mapsto\frac{z+z_0}{\overline{z_0}z+1}$ is a Mobius transformation that is biholomorphic on $D$ and send $\partial D$ to itself. Hence $g(0)=0$ is the only (simple) zero of $g$ over $\overline{D}$.
By Schwarz lemma, we have $0<|z|<1\Rightarrow |g(z)|<|z|$ (otherwise $g(z)=az$ is injective), $|\frac{z}{g(z)}|>1$ for all $0<|z|<1$. However, if $g(z)$ has no other zeroes, $\frac{z}{g(z)}$ is also analytic over $D$ and continuous over $\overline{D}$. Thus by maximum modulus principle, $|\frac{z}{g(z)}|\le \max_{w\in\partial D}|\frac{w}{g(w)}|=1$, a contradiction.

Nice. This is a bit simpler than my solution (+1).

@Gerd thank you! Actually I think your proof is better and easier to remember. Each term in the Blaschke product is just a Mobius transformation, so you have only used the division twice with the same transformation, which is more elegant than using composition and division with two different Mobius ($z\mapsto z$ is also a Mobius transformation) as in my answer. Even the Schwarz lemma is just to analyze $g(z)/z$. So it's really just to bring the zero to the origin and apply your argument.
